# Android ListView add not clickable TextView

Tags: java, android, list, listview, android-listview

I have list view:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And I add some items to it:

```
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); ++i) {
        try {
            list.add(items[i].getString("title"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But now  I want to add some `TextViews` (at example `if(i==5)`) to the list, like a label. It should not be clickable.
How can I add it?

Answer (score 0):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,long arg3) 
{
 long pos = arg0.getItemIdAtPosition(arg2);
if(pos != 5)
    {
    //add textview
    }
    else
    {
    //nothing
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom row layout instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, for example a row.xml you have one text view whose visibility is set to gone by default:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nonclickable_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/normal_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Put it in res/layout/ folder, then call `R.layout.row` instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` when you create your StableArrayAdapter. In the getView() method

```
@Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent,false);
    }

    if(int position==5) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nonclickable_text);
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```